# How to update part of a schema object without replacing it (Mongoose schema in node.js api)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I am very new to node.js and mongoose so bare with me if my question isn't using the right terms. I'm amazed I've gotten this far so quickly!

My main schema is a grocery list, which can have a listItemDict object, and an array of sale objects. I can PUT any field from the main schema and it will update just that field - the other fields stay as they were. But if I PUT any field from the sale schema, it replaces any sale data that was there.

My schema's are defined like this

```
var listItemDictSchema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
      name: String,
      details: String,
      aisle: String,
      aisleSort: Number
    }
  ); 

  var saleSchema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
      store: String,
      price: Number,
      quantity: Number,
      quantityUnit: String,
      details: String,
      startDate: Date,
      endDate: Date
    }
  )
  
  var schema = mongoose.Schema(
      {
        name: String,
        details: String,
        quantity: Number,
        quantityUnit: String,
        priority: String,
        forDate: Date
        listItemDict: listItemDictSchema,
        sales: [saleSchema]
      },
      { timestamps: true }
    );
```

This is a sample mongodb entry

```
_id:621ca04410e73258802a619d
name:"Bread"
details:""
quantity:1
quantityUnit:"loaf"
priority:"Normal"
listItemDict:Object
sales:
Array:
0:Object
  _id:621ca66f10e73258802a61a5
  store:"Store 1"
  details:"BOGO"
  price:1.99
1:
  Object
  _id:621ca66f10e73258802a61a6
  store:"Store 2"
  price:2.2
  createdAt:2022-02-28T10:13:24.312+00:00
  updatedAt:2022-02-28T10:39:43.768+00:00
```

If I **put**

```
{
"quantity": 2
}
```

just the quantity is updated and everything else stays the same, which I think is the right behaviour.

If I **put**

```
"sales": [{
    "id": "621ca66f10e73258802a61a5",
    "store": "Store 3"
}]
```

it replaces all sale info with this.

How can I update one piece of a sale object without replacing all sale data?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the quantity of specific sales then pick sale document first by id and then update the fields you want in $set:

```
SalesModel.findByIdAndUpdate('id',{
   $set:{
      quantity:10
   }
})
```